# Time difference on server-client after submission

Tags: c#, silverlight, datetime

I have a Silverlight application for agent evaluation. When doing the evaluation the DateTime is displayed correctly but after I subbmit an evaluation where I want to edit it later on I see that there is a -5 hour difference. The client is from Canada but the server seems to be somewhere else. I have read a little bit about it (have to use UTCDateTime) but it's a little hard to test because the application has to be deployed to be tested so that I don't want to be shooting in the dark.

Any help?

Edit: This is how I create the Evaluation

```
CurrentEvaluation = new Evaluation();
CurrentEvaluation.CreatedBy = UserID;
CurrentEvaluation.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
CurrentEvaluation.EvaluatorID = UserID;
CurrentEvaluation.EvaluationDate = DateTime.Now;
CurrentEvaluation.UserID = CurrentUser.UserID;
CurrentEvaluation.TenantID = CurrentTenant.TenantID;
```

Is it enough to say just `CurrentEvaluation.EvaluationDate = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();` and then convert it back to local time?

Comment: Code please for how you insert and use the retrieved data

Comment: Why not use UTCDateTime and .ToLocalTime() for display correct date?

Comment: `DateTime.Now` would be local time on the server, you should know the offset in UTC of the client and store date in UTC and then return by using the offset which would present it in local time for the client

Comment: Why don't you just load your server code on a virtual machine and change the timezone there... It's easy and you will be able to check for more problems. You could event switch the VM to a test pseudo locale to check for date -> string conversions and things like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be overkill for your specific example, but when dealing with date/times that originate from different timezones (different to the server or also between clients), it is best to store them using the new [DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) structure introduced in Silverlight 3 along with the [datetimeoffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx) field type of SQL Server 2008 R2.

This gives you the power to determine not just "universal time", but also to know what the times are *relative to any given client*.

When RIA services first came out it did not support the DateTimeOffset type (so we had to bodge a fix involving a DateTime and an int offset), but that was corrected in a later RIA service pack so you can use DateTimeOffsets as they were intended.